# What's with the Comic Sans-like font for Bold and Italic?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Everywhere on RPG.SE Meta, there is a clean, crisp serif font. Everywhere that is, except for the edit buttons:

[image]

Notice the B (for bold), the I (for italics), and the quotes (for block text). They are in this strange, Comic Sans-like font. This clashes pretty badly with the rest of the site's aesthetic, as it isn't anywhere close to the font used elswewhere.

Would it be possible to change this to a font more in line with the rest of Meta?

Comment: As far as I know, those are built in to the WYSIWYG editor, which is not under the control of the site's design. I doubt the SE devs would consider changing it to be a reasonable time/cost trade, either.

Comment: [Redesigned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359/152515) sites such as [Programmers.se] have a non-sketchy WYSIWYG button panel. However even some of the sites which are not yet redesigned, like [travel.se], have the same appearance.

Comment: @doppelgreener Travel does have the redesign (it has the new profile views), so that's probably the answer: we'll get the same set of nicer editor buttons when they get around to upgrading RPG.se.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the site CSS updates are complete, the editor buttons will look just like they do on other sites (although only options relevant to RPG.SE will be here):

[image: toolbar]

Comment: Is there an ETA for the CSS updates? Days? Months? A year?

Comment: @Thunderforge We're working through this list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed. At this time I think MathOverflow, Stack Apps, and Seasoned Advice are about to go live. Just a few more sites and we'll work on converting RPG.SE. I don't have an exact timeline, but we're working through a couple a week, so it should be a few weeks now.

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks for your quick reply!